# Can I hyper link large source data in manuscript?

Tags: publications

I have prepared a manuscripts in which there is very large set of equations almost covering 3 pages on manuscript. Although these actions are major source of analysis in my manuscript but their beast size concerns me. To save space I am thinking of hyperlinking these equations to my personal webpage so that reviewer can access these equations from my personal page. Is this a good idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should definitely not supply them as a link to your personal page.  One reason is that it looks suspicious, since you could try to identify anonymous reviewers based on server logs.  Another is that if these equations are important enough to supply to the reviewers, then they need to be made permanently available to all readers.  If you feel they are too long for the main text, you could include them as an appendix.  If you feel they are too long for an appendix, you could include them in a separate file of supplementary material (submitted together with the main text of your paper, and permanently archived by the publisher).  Either way is much better than a personal web page that will not be permanently maintained.